# Is there a way to perform XPath queries in Visual Studios Code?

Tags: xpath, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to perform XPath queries in Visual Studios Code? I've tried XML Tools from Josh Johnson and XSLT/XPATH from DeltaXML but while both format/display the XML nicely, neither has an XPath command. (Their documentation says they do, but the actual extension does not.)

So.. is there some extension that does provide this functionality? (I'm not asking for an opinion of what is the best, just is there a way to do this.)

Answer (score 1):

There is an XPath Notebook extension. XPath Code cells added to a notebook can be executed via the user interface. This supports XPath 3.1. The XPath Processor is SaxonJS (NodeJS must be installed). https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deltaxml.xpath-notebook